# isnull function does not return correct

Tags: sql, sql-server, isnull

[image]

When I am using isnull it does not return the '' please see below I have original DOB, isnull used, cast as date.

Comment: When you are casting `''` to a `DATETIME` the value returned is `1900-01-01 00:00:00`.  It is doing exactly what you're telling it to do.  Perhaps you're looking for something like: `Case When Dob Is Null Then '' Else Convert(Varchar (15), Dob) End As IsNull`

Comment: Why are you trying to suppress a NULL here anyway?

Comment: @SeanLange im pulling a patient dob with age. when patient dob is null then i want to display ''. thanks...

Comment: You should allow it to return NULL from the database. If you want a NULL to display as an empty string you should handle this in the front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to convert `dob` to a `char/nchar/varchar/nvarchar` type to use `isnull()` or `coalesce()` like that.

```
select isnull(convert(varchar(10),dob,120),'')
```

Answer (score 1):

if you really would like to return an empty string for the date value, you could try this in a new query window. It creates a table to repoduce your requirement of a null date value and then selects the value before dropping the table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
(
Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
,Date1 DATE NULL
)

INSERT INTO dbo.Test(Date1) VALUES ('01/01/2017')
INSERT INTO dbo.Test(Date1) VALUES ('01/02/2017')
INSERT INTO dbo.Test(Date1) VALUES (NULL)
INSERT INTO dbo.Test(Date1) VALUES ('01/04/2017')

SELECT * FROM dbo.Test

SELECT Date1 = CASE WHEN date1 IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CAST(DATE1 AS    VARCHAR(10)) END from dbo.Test

DROP TABLE dbo.Test
go
```